# Windows key is activated whenever touchpad is used

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad

I am experiencing a strange problem on my Windows laptop. Whenever I am using the touchpad, the windows key is activated and my notification bar (which is commonly activated by pressing 4 fingers simultaneously) also pops out. This problem only occurs when I use a touchpad, and I managed to overcome it by using a mouse. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Hi Gilbert and welcome to superuser. What have you done so far to fix the problem? Did you search for the issue to see if others have had similar problems? Besides using a mouse, what else did you try? Did you re-install the touchpad drivers? Restart? What laptop model do you have? Did you try disabling the 4 finger gesture?

Comment: Also, whenever I press the windows key, my start menu is shown, not the notification bar. So how did you determine that the windows key is being activated when you use the touchpad?